# Arbitrary precision gamma function

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, floating-point, gamma-function

I'm implementing an arbitrary precision arithmetic library in C++ and I'm pretty much stuck when implementing the gamma function.

By using the equivalences `gamma(n) = gamma(n - 1) * n` and `gamma(n) = gamma(n + 1) / n`, respectively, I can obtain a rational number `r` in the range `(1; 2]` for all real values `x`.

However, I don't know how to evaluate `gamma(r)`. For the Lanczos approximation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation), I need precomputed values p which happen to calculate a factorial of a non-integer value (?!) and can't be calculated dynamically with my current knowledge... Precomputing values for p wouldn't make much sense when implementing an arbitrary precision library.

Are there any algorithms that compute `gamma(r)` in a reasonable amount of time with arbitrary precision? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I presume you have studied http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/introductions/Gamma/05/ and failed to find what you need.

Comment: Looks like it's more related to math than to programming... Maybe, it's better to post question there.

Comment: I'd also look into MPFR's source to see what they use.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov: I think it's reasonably on-topic, given the practical constraints of an efficient implementation.

Comment: Second 4.5 of Modern Computer Arithmetic (official PDF [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=modern+computer+arithmetic&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=B0grWITKAc3FaJb8i9AP)) gives one approach, which is to use Stirling's asymptotic expansion for large `x`, and the functional equation to transfer this to smaller `x`. (The reflection formula lets you extend this to negative `x` efficiently.)

Comment: BTW, I just checked the MPFR source: it uses exactly the approach described above (Stirling's expansion + functional equation + reflection formula). Not a huge surprise, given that Paul Zimmerman is a coauthor of both MPFR and MCA. Check out `src/lngamma.c` in the MPFR source for details.

Answer (score 4):

[Spouge's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spouge%27s_approximation) is similar to Lanczos's approximation, but probably easier to use for arbitrary precision, as you can set the desired error.

Answer (score 1):

Lanczos approximation doesn't seem too bad. What exactly do you suspect?

Parts of code which calculate `p`, `C` (Chebyshev polynomials) and `(a + 1/2)!` can be implemented as stateful objects so that, for example, you can calculate `p(i)` from `p(i-1)` and Chebyshev coefficients and be computed once, maintaining their matrix.